# Android convert 2D image to 3D

Tags: android, dicom

I got dozens of DICOM images, and I have to convert it into a 3D image in an Android device, any advice about how to do it, as I never handle any imaging like this before, I have no idea............

Comment: It can also convert it in a server and then send the converted image to the device, guess this will make the task easier, right??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search term you are looking for is "Volume Rendering".  This is a deep, complicated topic.  If you're looking for a place to get started learning, I'd recommend reading the relevant sections of "Handbook of Medical Imaging:  Processing and Analysis", Isaac Bankman (ed.), ISBN# 0-12-077790-8.

Answer (score 1):

Volume rendering of DICOM images is computationally very demanding, and DICOM is a complex protocol.  Partly for these reasons, only a few implementations of DICOM viewers exist on mobile devices, versus hundreds on desktop/laptops.  And most of these are 2D viewers which are more commonly used in clinical applications.  There is no open source DICOM toolkit I know of for mobile devices (there are plenty for Unix/Mac/Windows).

For an example of a good implementation, look at the iPad/iPhone versions of Osirix.  Further resources available on my website [I Do Imaging](http://www.idoimaging.com)

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is probably to get involved with Xbox360 Kinect hacking/research and use the Kinect's 3D mapping functionality to convert your 2D images to a 3D scene.  Kinect is probably the most robust 2D to 3D mapping system in the world right now - you're not likely to find much else.